# How do I set an environment variable using docker service create?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

The command line arguments listed here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create

Does not specify the exact syntax, only `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained further down the page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#set-environment-variables--e-env

`--env MYVAR=foo`